# Postman - Ignore test execution based on environment

Tags: postman

In Postman, is there a way to ignore a specific test execution based upon environment at runtime?
I have a collection which consists of around 30 tests and I don't want 4-5 tests to execute on production environment at runtime but because they are meant to be executed on staging only.
I don't want to have multiple collections for different environments.
Any way I can make use of pre-request scripts in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @joroe that a simple way to conditionally add tests is with a variable and check that variable before each test that is conditional.

If you want to not have the test sent to the server at all you probably want to explore the collection runner and group your into collections according to the environment.  For example you may group your requests into a collection called PROD Tests that runs requests 1-10.  You can have a second collection called DEV Tests that contains requests 1-15 (the ten from PROD plus the five others you don't want to run in PROD).  It's very easy to copy a request from one collection to another.  You then in the test runner run the collection for the specific environment.  You can even automate this using the [Newman extension](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/).  I'm not super familiar but there is documentation at the link posted.  I've included a screen capture of the collection runner interface and how I have some of my tests set up to run.

[image]

Comment: Got the idea. Thanks guys, much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a possibility of calling tests from another collection based on environmental state maybe based on a user defined envt variable? Maybe I want to run some tests cases from another collection some time and not another time based on user input along with a need to keep them separated in different collections for easy categorization.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable in each environment ("ENV") with name of the environment ("LOCAL").

```
if(environment.ENV === "LOCAL") tests["Run in local environment"] = true;
```

Comment: But doesn't it still send the request to Production?
I'm sorry if I have not made myself clear earlier. 
I want some specific requests should not be sent to prod server while they should be executed on staging from the same collection.